# How to calculate the integral of cos

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate below integral but I'm not able to do so:

$$\int 120\sqrt2\cdot\cos(2\pi\cdot60t)\ \mathrm dt = 120 \sqrt2 \cdot \int \cos(2\pi\cdot 60t)\ \mathrm dt$$

What is $\int \cos(2\pi \cdot 60t) \ \mathrm dt$?
I can understand that $\int \cos x \ \mathrm dx = \sin x + C$ and $\int \cos(2x)\ \mathrm dx = \frac12 \sin x + C$. But with $\pi$ in the middle, I can't really get that out of the $\cos$ function, or I don't know how.

The integral should be calculated in the wave period, which I think it's $\frac1{60}$. So the final value (middle value) would be something like $F(\frac1{60}) - F(0)$.

But my main concern is how to compute the integral of the first formula.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: You want to calculate $\int_{0}^{1/60} \cos( 120\pi t) dt$, right? Can you maybe change the variable $t$ such that you can use one of your standard integrals (the second of which is incorrect by the way). Maybe $t'  = t/60$? Or maybe you can already say something about the integral of cos x along 1 period?

Comment: If you can do it for $\cos 2x$, why not for $\cos ax$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pi$ is just another constant. Find that $\sin(ax)' = a\cos(ax)$ by the chain rule. This gives you
$$\int \cos(ax) \ \mathrm dx = \frac1a \sin(ax)$$
So in particular
$$\int \cos(2\pi\cdot 60 t) \ \mathrm dt = \frac1{120\pi} \sin(120\pi t) + C$$
As you noted correctly, the period of this function is $\frac1{60}$ so the definite integral would be
$$\frac1{120\pi} (\sin 2\pi - \sin 0) = 0$$

NB that you made a mistake: $\int \cos \frac 2x \ \mathrm dx = \frac12 \sin 2x$, note the argument of $\sin$ is $2x$ and not $x$.

Comment: I understand that pi is a constant, but this is not pi in the normal sense (3.14...), it's pi radian. Does it mean the same and can be used in the same way outside the trigonometric function, being pi radian (not sure if I'm properly writing that in english)?